# Ground state of Beryllium (${\rm Be}$)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals, term-symbols

Why is the ground state of Beryllium (${\rm Be}$) with electronic configuration $[{\rm He}]2s^2$ is $^1S_0$ and not $^3S_1$? The state $^3S_1$ has higher spin multiplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such state. A triplet $^3S$ spin state would be exchange-symmetric on the spin sector, which would require an antisymmetric state on the orbital sector, and this is impossible on a $2s^2$ orbital configuration, since both electrons are in the same state and that is intrinsically symmetric.

(On the other hand, a $^3S_1$ state is perfectly possible, say, in a $1s\: 2s$ configuration. But it will be extremely hard to find a real atomic system with a ground state of that type, as the higher energy of the $2s$ (or other such orbital) means that flipping to a $^1S$ configuration by dropping to both electrons on the lower orbital will be energetically favourable. And, indeed, a short scan using the Mathematica curated ElementData shows that no real atoms have a $^3S_1$ ground state.)

The Hund maximum-multiplicity rule does provide the ground state (except in the cases where it breaks), but you need to maximize over the set of states that do exist ;-).

Comment: _" since both electrons are in the same state and that is intrinsically symmetric"_ I did not understand this. All I can see is that total $L=0$.

Comment: Again, this is specific to the configuration ($[\mathrm{He}]\ 2s^2$) and not just the total orbital angular momentum. If you have more than one different $s$ orbital to occupy, then the triplet state is possible, but with both electrons in the $2s$ orbital, an antisymmetric spatial state isn't possible.

Comment: Does $L=0$ mean the spatial part of the wavefunction symmetric? Doesn't the $L$ value determine the orbital parity only? Thanks!

Comment: @mithusengupta I can't answer that without repeating myself a third time, so I'll just refer you to the answer and my first comment.